# Give me an example for this type of method?

Tags: c#

Please show me a simple code with class name as return type in a method? Some of the codings in project as classname as return type for methods? I don't understand What that mean?

Can anyone give me a breif explanation and simple example regarding that one?

For example

```
public Dataset getEmployees()
{
-----
----
------
}
```

In the above code we are using (`Dataset`)(It's basically a class) but here we are using as return type for `getEmployees` method.

I want the same as example. Instead of `Dataset`,user defined class should be as return type. I hope you understand what my doubt is.

Comment: This is a type of class instance returned by method. Use `public YourType GetSomethin() { return new YourType(); }` to return your type

Comment: I think better just read a simple book about c#, no?

Comment: Are you referring to [C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Classes and return values are pretty fundamental concepts - revisiting some basic C# training may pay dividends here.

Comment: In c# every method returning a value returns a class (the methods that do not return a value return `void`). `int`, `string` and company are also class names, they are just defined by the system.

Comment: @SWeko that gets into a terminology hazard zone, though; in IL terms those are classes; in C# terms, `int` is *not* a class. There are other types that are explicitly **not** classes in any way, such as `byte*`

Answer (score 1):

consider a user defined class:

```
public class Manipulator{
    class UserDefined{
      private int data;
      public int getData(){ return data;}
      public void setData(int d) {data = d;}
      public UserDefined(){ d = 0; }
    }

    public UserDefined returnUserDefined()
    {
       return new UserDefined();
    }

    public void doSomethingWithIt(UserDefined d)
    {
       d.setData(500);
    }

    public int getDataWithingUserDefined(UserDefined d)
    {
       return d.getData();
    }
}
```

From the above methods, you can see that, how to return/use an object of `UserDefined` type(or class)

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
public class ExampleItem
{
    public string MyString;
    public ExampleItem(string stringToUse)
    {
       this.MyString = stringToUse;
    }

    public ExampleItem MakeExampleItem(string str)
    {
       return new ExampleItem(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: that should be makeMyObject(String str){ }

Comment: @Aniket Looks fine to me.  The method is making an instance of `MyClass`, hence `MakeMyClass`.

Comment: to me it looks like its making an object of `MyClass`, not `MyClass` itself.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it's doing, making an object of `MyClass`, the same way most methods called `MakeString()` make objects of type `String`, not the `String` class itself, but since it seems to be confusing you, I've modified it to make it less confusing.  Better now?

Answer (score 0):

Since "getEmployees" suggests more than one result, it sounds like you just want:

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees() { ... }
```

? Or have I understood the question?

Comment: OH GOD! Generics to explain UserDefined return types? :O

Comment: @Aniket well, it could return just a vector (`Employee[]`) - happier?

Comment: I prefer generics over arrays; I agree with your first choice.  THough maybe `IEnumerable<Employee>` would be better.

Comment: @Brian yeah, but then we need to think about concrete vs abstract types ... and is the enumerable deferred? buffered? what? A concrete list / vector is probably enough for now, given the nature of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to return a `List<Employee>` or `IEnumerable<Employee>`:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a method that returns it (assuming SQL-Server as rdbms for demonstration purposes):

```
public static IEnumerable<Employee> getAllEmployees()
{
    string sql = "SELECT EmpID, Name FROM Employee ORDER BY Name";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var list = new List<Employee>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var emp = new Employee();
                    emp.EmpID = dr.GetInt32(0);
                    emp.Name = dr.GetString(1);
                    list.Add(emp);
                }
                return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```